# r commands for merging multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv

Friends, 
I got the following code for combining multiple csv files in a particular folder, the person who helped me in trying this code, for him its works well... but when I use it, it is **not** showing any errors but in the output **I m getting only the headers and not the data.**

can you please suggest me how to overcome this please???
the code would be like the following,

```
setwd("C:/Users/dsuresh/Desktop/io")

multmerge = function(mypath){
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=T)})
  Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, datalist)
}
mydata=multmerge("C:/Users/dsuresh/Desktop/io")
View(mydata)
```

thanks for your time friends...

Comment: @koundy thanks for your time koundy.. I tried by replacing read.csv by read.table .... even then it is showing only the headers... basically my headers are name and area3d. earlier the output was like row.names name area_3d    and now the output was row.names,  name.area_3d. not much difference. how to overcome this???

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Check the contents of `filenames` and `datalist`. I agree with @koundy, your problem is probably the `merge` step. I suspect you need to specify the columns `by` which the data.frame should be merged.

Comment: @Roland:  
thanks for your great help.. actually your suggestion and koundy suggestion made me to succeed in combining all my csv files 98% perfectly :). thanks lot... but only problem is its not maintaining the order of the common field based on which the files has to be combined. in other words, my common field name in the file and the data in this column looks like A-2:1 A-2:2 A-2:3 A-2:4 A-2:5  .......... ......... A-2:232 A-2:233 A-2:234 B-1:1 B-1:2 B-1:3 B-1:4 B-1:5 B-1:6 B-1:7 B-1:8 ..... ........ B-1:229 B-1:230 B-1:231 B-1:232 B-1:233 B-1:234 sorry I ll cont in d next comment

Comment: so what I tried is sort = False.. its works to a certain extent.. but wherever I am getting missing values its going down the row separately... but I don't want like this... it has to maintain the same order like the common field... pls help me with this...also can you pls tell me how to get the file names in the header since I m having date in the names of 100 files , I need them to be on the header to identify which file is which????

Comment: @Roland- is there is anyway to attach my csv file to this forum... so that it will be very clear to you what I am requesting you for????

Answer (score 1):

I think your file is not proper .csv (comma seperated values file). try replacing `read.csv` function with `read.table` and check. Otherwise there is no problem in this function.If doesnt work, try using `rbind` instead of `merge`. merge function matches two columns from data and then merges. If your data doesn't have identical rownames or columns it won't work properly.

Comment: I understoond your point... my csv files basically all are same and I have a common field called name in al the csv files. thn if I use rbind I ll be getting merged down by down right.. I don't want like this I want to combine horizontally like what this cbind does (but for cbind, I need equal data frames, but mine are not so I cannot use) so merge is the only option I hope... but I m not getting proper output.. please help me

Comment: If your data frames doesn't have equal rows i don't know how to merge them.

Comment: thanks for your great help.. actually your suggestion and @Roland suggestion made me to succeed in combining all my csv files 98% perfectly :). thanks lot... but only  problem is its not maintaining the order of the common field based on which the files has to be combined. 

in other words, my common field  **name** in the file and the data in this column looks like 
A-2:1
A-2:2
A-2:3
A-2:4
A-2:5
..........
..........
.........
A-2:232
A-2:233
A-2:234
B-1:1
B-1:2
B-1:3
B-1:4
B-1:5
B-1:6
B-1:7
B-1:8
.....
........
B-1:229
B-1:230
B-1:231
B-1:232
B-1:233
B-1:234
sorry I ll cont in d next comment

Comment: so what I tried is **sort = False**.. its works to a certain extent.. but wherever I am getting missing values its going down the row separately... but I don't want like this... it has to maintain the same order like the common field... pls help me with this...also can you pls tell me how to get the file names in the header since I m having date in the names of 100 files , I need them  to be on the header to identify which file is which????

Comment: Im not aware of these kind of problems, i would suggest you to ask another question in stackoverflow so that someone else will answer you.

Answer (score 0):

`rbind` works perfectly in your case.

```
csvFile1 = "col1,col2,col3\na1,a2,a3\nb1,b2,b3"
csvFile2 = "col1,col2,col3\nc1,c2,c3\nd1,d2,d3"
csvFile3 = "col1,col2,col3\ne1,e2,e3\nf1,f2,f3"
con1 = textConnection(csvFile1)
con2 = textConnection(csvFile2)
con3 = textConnection(csvFile3)
csvList = list(con1, con2, con3)

multmerge = function(files){
  datalist = lapply(files, read.csv)
  Reduce(rbind, datalist)
}

mydata=multmerge(csvList)
View(mydata)
```

Moreover, you could do just `do.call(rbind, datalist)` instead of `Reduce`
And you have no need to specify `header=T` in `read.csv` - it is default option.